# How do you make a feature method conditional

Tags: spock, geb

In my Test, I have some feature methods that only need to run in certain situations. My code looks something like this:

```
class MyTest extends GebReportingSpec{

    def "Feature method 1"(){
        when:
        blah()
        then:
        doSomeStuff()
    }

    def "Feature method 2"(){
        if(someCondition){
            when:
            blah()
            then:
            doSomeMoreStuff()
        }
    }

    def "Feature method 3"(){
        when:
        blah()
        then:
        doTheFinalStuff()
    }
}
```

I should note I am using a custom spock extension that allows me to run all feature methods of a spec even if a previous feature method fails.

The thing I just realized and the reason I am making this post, is because "Feature method 2" does not show up in my test results for some reason, but method 1 and 3 do. Even if `someCondition` is set to true, it does not appear in the build results. so I am wondering why this is, and how I can make this feature method conditional

Comment: "I should note I am using a custom spock extension that allows me to run all feature methods of a spec even if a previous feature method fails." that is the normal behavior. Are you using `@Stepwise` without really wanting its behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spock has special support for conditionally executing features, take a look at [@IgnoreIf](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/all_in_one.html#_ignoreif) and [@Requires](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/all_in_one.html#_requires).

```
@IgnoreIf({ os.windows })
def "I'll run everywhere but on Windows"() { ... }
```

You can also use static methods in the condition closure, they need to use the qualified version.

```
class MyTest extends GebReportingSpec {
  @Requires({ MyTest.myCondition() })
  def "I'll only run if myCondition() returns true"() { ... }

  static boolean myCondition() { true }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your test is not appearing in the report as you cant have the `given`, `when`, `then` blocks inside of a conditional.

You should always run the test but allow the test to fail gracefully:

Use the `@FailsWith` attribute. http://spockframework.org/spock/javadoc/1.0/spock/lang/FailsWith.html

```
@FailsWith(value = SpockAssertionError, reason = "Feature is not enabled")
def "Feature method 2"(){

    when:
    blah()
    then:
    doSomeMoreStuff()
}
```

Important to note that this test will be reported as *passed* when it fails with the specified exception. And it will also reported as *passed* if the feature is enabled and the test actually passed.

Answer (score 0):

To Fix this I simply put a when/then block with a 10 ms sleep before the if statement and now that feature method is being executed